# Calling 'Read' when the data reader is closed is not a valid operation in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext

I am using Entity Framework in windows application C#,  Trying to retrieve data from two entities using DbContext and want to make simple join, but my code breakdown (at var modellst line). My sample code is as below

```
        using (var ctx = new DbEntities())
        {

            var lst = ctx.AUMaterials.Where(o => o.ServiceRequestTypeId == serviceReqId && o.SSStock.Quantity > 0).ToList();
            var modellst = ctx.AUModelMaterials.Where(o => o.ModelId == modelId).ToList();

            // here i want to make join on these two list
        }
```

Here in first list thousands of records in AUMaterials entity. And I think it will take to much time to load. Same way in AUModelMaterials entity, Here also thousands of records. But same code works fine in earlier stage.

Comment: Do you have navigation properties or collection properties?

Comment: Here AUMaterials, AUModelMaterials, SSStock are related to each other.AUMaterials to AUModelMaterials one to many relationship, while  AUMaterials to SSStock  one to one relationship.

Comment: And my entity 'AUMaterial' having properties like 
        public virtual ICollection<AUModelMaterial> AUModelMaterials { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var results = (from t1 in context.AUMaterials
                      join t2 in context.AUModelMaterials
                      on  t1.Col1 equals t2.Col1
                      where t1.ServiceRequestTypeId == serviceReqId && t1.SSStock.Quantity > 0 && t2.ModelId == modelId
                      select new { t1, t2}).ToList();
```

[Joining](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx) on multiple columns

```
 var results = (from t1 in context.AUMaterials
                      join t2 in context.AUModelMaterials
                      on new {t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3 } equals
                          new { t2.Col1, t2.Col2, t2.Col3 }
                      where t1.ServiceRequestTypeId == serviceReqId && t1.SSStock.Quantity > 0 && t2.ModelId == modelId
                      select new { t1, t2}).ToList();
```